# Remove ListView Row when Button (delete) Pressed

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, android-arrayadapter

Currently I use an `ArrayAdapter` to create many rows of ListView items. In each of those rows is a button to delete that "task". I can make the task be deleted from the database, but I don't know how to find the view item and actually delete it visually so the user sees it removed. Any Help? Below is my `getView`. (Thanks for any suggestions!)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final DataManager dm = new DataManager(getContext());
    Task task = objects.get(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = 
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_task, null);

    // Get Text Views
    TextView tv_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    TextView tv_item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_item);
    ImageView iv_delete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_delete_image);

    tv_title.setText(task.getTitle());
    tv_item.setText(task.getItem());
    iv_delete.setTag(task.getId());

    iv_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String tag_del = (String) v.getTag();
            dm.deleteItem(tag_del);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Delete the entry from Task list and call notifyDataSetChanged()..it might work for you.
OR

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please give me a hint at where I can look to learn how to delete an entry? I'm not sure of the method.

Comment: You can simply remove item from ArrayList by using item.remove(position) and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the item from the array or (whatever collection you have used to fill the list in your Activity), and after that call `notifyDataSetChanged();` on your adapter`to update the list

e.g.

if you use an `ArrayList<String> list` to define

```
 final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

calling

```
list.remove(3);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
```

the 4th row of your `ListView` will be removed

Answer (score 0):

The fix was, in the adapter where the onclick is, add the following inside the onclick:

```
objects.remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 iv_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            remove(task);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

try this i am doing like this in my project